# How the validator rewards get persisted on NEAR protocol?

Tags: nearprotocol

I am trying to get an understanding of validator rewards. I haven't seen any transactions related to rewards get issued, and I don't understand how the reward is persisted otherwise (it seems to be fine to keep that info in memory during the epoch, but it is unclear what happens beyond that point).

How does one track the rewards? Is `changes` API expected to expose the "intermediate" rewards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewards are added to validator accounts automatically at the beginning of an epoch. The corresponding state change is a `ValidatorAccountUpdate`.

Comment: “At the beginning” - does it imply that the reward is issued ahead of time? Or it simply refers to “the beginning of the epoch next to the one validators are getting rewards for”?

Comment: The beginning of next epoch.

Comment: How does one distinguish the reward from the return of the stake and slashing, and possibly something else in the future?

Comment: Well reward is also nonnegative whereas slashing will cause locked balance to decrease. I think even if we have something else in the future it will be of a similar nature to rewards and will be handled in the same way.